# For CiviCampaign - how can I enable any user to see Canvass and other Activities entered by another user via a webform?

Tags: activities, civicampaign

We're on Civi 4.6.9, Drupal 7.

I've installed and am using the CiviCampaign component. I like it. I've used the Canvass activity type added by CiviCampaign in a webform, created using the webform-civicrm Drupal module. Here's a screenshot of the webform CiviCRM activity field. [image: screenshot]

Now, I want to enable any user to see Canvass activities that any other user has entered using the webform.

In Civi, only the Added by: user, the Assigned To: user (if any), the "target" contact and an Admin (me) can see the Activities in the Added by: or Assigned To: user's record.

There are other users who oversee volunteer users entering Canvass activities (the Added by: user), as well as staff and volunteers conducting the canvass (the Assigned to: user) that need to be able to see all the Activities data entered in each contact's Activities list.

I can and have created Groups of the target contacts who have the relevant Canvass activity and any user can see the Contacts in the relevant Group.

I've looked [here](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/campaign/setup/) and elsewhere. I've also tweaked the CiviCampaign permissions. No luck so far.

Comment: I haven't used that component extensively, but is it possible you can create a Drupal View that pulls the info you want to share? If so you could even get the benefit of exposed filters and sortable table rows pretty easily.

Comment: Laryn, thanks, and it might be possible with Drupal Views - and I will try that again - but I'm trying to keep using Civi as simple as I can for my users, and much prefer that they can see the info in the Civi interface that they are still getting used to, even if I can create a View that will appear as a 'sidebar' to logged-in users.

Comment: I am not sure I'm understanding the question. CiviCampaign only adds activities. Nothing else and nothing special. If a contact has been assigned to be called, then any user should be able to lookup that contact, click the Activities tab, and see it listed. Similarly, any contact should be able to search for matching activites in the activities search and find them. If I'm off base... can you more clearly specify exactly the steps you are taking?

Comment: Jamie, thanks for the good questions. I've edited the explanation above to add some clarification on how I'm using the Canvass activity type, and a webform edit screenshot. I left out the webform part in the original explanation.

Comment: Jamie I'm also realizing this could of course be a misconfig by me of the webform and not at all related to the Canvass activity type. So I'll take a look at the webform settings. And I'll seek some guidance re webform-civicrm settings on the module page and elsewhere.

Comment: resurrecting this. Jamie - does it make sense to you that Activity Type = Canvass is not available as an option under Activity Types eg in a CiviReport based on Activities? Nor is it available as an Activity Type in a Drupal views filter. And what proved to be the issue for Joe, in one respect at least, that a User who is assigned/undertakes a Canvass cannot see them on their Activity Tab unless they are given Administer CiviCampaign permissions - which seems wrong imo. i will add last bit as an Answer joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that a user can only see Activity Types = Canvass on their Activity Tab if they are given the "administer CiviCampaign" permission.

Also it seems that perhaps because Canvass is an Activity Type related to Entity = CiviCampaign that

- it is not available in a Drupal Views as an Activity Type filter
- it is not available as an Activity Type filter on an Activities report.

Jamie - any thoughts on how to unlock this? anything to do with component_id being 9 in the civicrm_option_value table?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I'm surprised by this too (and also surprised we never hit this problem). It seems to be quite intentional in the code (on 4.6 it's in /CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php in the activityComponents() function). It clearly says that for any CiviCampaign component, you must have CiviCampaign Admin privs to see. We should be pushing out our 4.7 version in the next few weeks and I've added this to my list of things to work on for that release.

Comment: Jamie thanks so much for the update and work on the next version